# Partialview not rendering and returns error 500 in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to render a partialview via a form tag ajax call in my index.cshtml. Don't know why the partialview always shows error 500 when using IE11 debugging tools to debugging it. The ajax call does work because the javascript function "onFailed" shows the message "Failed: object object".

Below is the index.cshtml code:

```
> <script>
    var onFailed = function (context) {
        alert("Failed: " + context);
    };
</script>

               <form asp-controller="ProcTracking" asp-action="EpSearchResults" id="epsForm"
                  data-ajax-update="#divSearch" data-ajax-mode="replace"
                  data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
                  data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="onSuccess"
                  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET">

...... (for brevity)

                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" onclick="return checkEntries()" class="btn btn-primary rounded btn-sm text-center"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" onclick="resetForm()" class="btn btn-warning rounded btn-sm text-center"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-refresh"></span> Reset</button>
                            </td>


</form>

        <div id="divSearch" class="mx-auto">

        </div>
```

Below is controller code: (This action does get called in VS debugger when debugging it)

```
>      [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult EpSearchResults(IFormCollection form, List<string> pi_status, List<string> bud_qtr, int Search_cat = 0, int Search_type = 0, int Search_mfg = 0)
        {
            TempData["xsearch"] = form["R1"];

            TempData["xpcat"] = Search_cat;

            TempData["xptype"] = Search_type;

            TempData["xpmfg"] = Search_mfg;

...... (for brevity)

            return PartialView("_EpSearchResults");
        }
```

Below is the _EpSearchResults.cshtml: (Only one line of text for debugging purpose and still not showing)

```
>     <h4 id="Nodata" class="text-center">You have made it!</h4>
```

Note: All of this stuff was working with MVC 5. I am converting it to .Net 5 (Core). I have spent 2 days on it and still not getting anywhere. I am new to .Net Core.

Comment: .NET 5 is different from .NET Core. I understand the confusion, because the name of the product you're running is ASP.NET Core MVC. But it's running on .NET 5. So this question should be tagged [.net-5] and [asp.net-core-mvc] since those are the two products you are using. Welcome to Microsoft Naming :). You may want to look at their [migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as well.

Comment: The product I am converting to .Net 5 is Asp.Net MVC; not Core. The reason I stated it as ".Net 5 (core)" is to ensure no one mistaken it with MVC 5 that's all. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   <form asp-controller="ProcTracking" asp-action="EpSearchResults" id="epsForm"
>                   data-ajax-update="#divSearch" data-ajax-mode="replace"
>                   data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
>                   data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="onSuccess"
>                   data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET">
> ```

To use the `data-ajax-*` load partial view in asp.net core application, in the View page, we still need to add the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` reference, code like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EpSearchResults" id="epsForm"
      data-ajax-update="#divSearch" data-ajax-mode="replace"
      data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
      data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="onSuccess"
      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" >
     
    <button type="submit" onclick="return checkEntries()" class="btn btn-primary rounded btn-sm text-center">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-search"></span> Search
    </button>

    <button type="button" onclick="resetForm()"
            class="btn btn-warning rounded btn-sm text-center">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-refresh"></span> Reset
    </button> 
</form>

<div id="divSearch" class="mx-auto">

</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var onFailed = function (context) {
            alert("Failed: " + context);
        };
        function checkEntries() {
            console.log("Check entities")
        }
        function onBegin() {
            console.log("Begin");
        }
        function onComplete() {
            console.log("complete");

        }
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("success");
        }
    </script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

For the 500 error, perhaps it relates the `EpSearchResults` action method, try to set a break point in this method and step by step to debug your code.

Comment: Thank you @Zhi Lv. The problem was the controller action below:         public IActionResult EpSearchResults(IFormCollection form)
        {
            //TempData["xsearch"] = form["R1"];   <== this statement breaks the partialview. IFormCollection is not giving me the values of the form fields. "R1" tells me which of the 2 submit buttons the user pressed.